Can I use questions from a published study when the questions haven't been published as a standalone measure? (PhD psychology research)
I'm a PhD candidate researching and evaluating the impact of interventions on children and young people. An existing published study that closely aligns with my own topic created a series of questions that would fit with my research very nicely. However, seemingly they haven't published those questions as a measure I can find. I would of course, contact them and seek permission but my question is:
Is it the 'done thing' to use questions from a published study when they haven't been made into a measure?
Thank you

What about doing this concerns you?  I mean, why wouldn't you be able to?

I don't understand the meaning of "they haven't been made into a measure". Can you explain "standalone measure"?

Yes, are you worried about the psychometric properties of using a partial scale, or rights infringement?

For people outside this field @PeterFlom & Buffy: it's common in psychology for instruments like questionnaires to be packaged and sold by a publisher (written or software). Copyright applies, and using the questionnaire for research or diagnosis requires purchasing a license or at least complying with some terms. There may also be required or optional training for instruments that involve more subjective/interactive aspects. This can be a bit controversial, of course, as it puts reproducing research behind a paywall, but the publishers may also invest substantially in validation, etc.

Hi, Thank you for responding. For clarity most research I've encountered uses validated/licensed measures. For example say, the Big Five personality test.
These are published and able to be used for research purposes.
The study I am considering asked participants a number of questions about their attitudes but hasn't put those questions into a published questionnaire so I'm wondering if it is appropriate to contact them & ask if I can reuse them

Does the paper have an appendix of all the questions they used? I would take that as implicit permission to use them.
